# Raspi has two static IP-Adresses assigned to it's adapters (WLAN0 & ETH0). How to find out that the Ethernet cable is plugged in & ETH0 is active?

Tags: networking

this is a detailing of my closed answer before:

I have two adapters WAN0 and ETH0. Both are assigned with (different) static IPs - both are properly working (also in parallel). I am aware of the routing problems with two active IP adresses in my network on the same board - this is not my question.

Question is: Which is the easy bash command helping me to find out e.g. when the EThernet cable is cut off and I am ssh-connected via WiFi moementarily THAT I AM WiFi connected?

The command "ip a" does not help me - as the IP-adresses are static and remain assigned (when the connection is cut) - otherwiese the DHCP mechanism would help me showing, that the adapter has no assigned ip adress, so the connection is missing. Easy!

But what to do, when the IPs are self assigend / static?

BR & Thanx

Comment: As already explained to you in the duplicate, "But what to do, when the IPs are self assigend / static?" is  to **use `ip route`** which clearly and unequivocally indicates what connections will/are taking place on which interface.  If you are still not satisified, please take your question to our larger sibling site, [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/), as it is really off-topic here since the brand of hardware you are using is irrelevant (== not a raspberry pi specific issue).

Comment: WRT "find out e.g. when the EThernet cable is cut off", `ip link` may shed some light but it is somewhat dependent on what "cut off" means.  If it is because the uplink is off-line, the only way you can test the connection is to try and use it (via `ping` etc).  *I would strongly recommend that if you do decide to ask on U&L that instead of posting a minimum of information, you describe **in detail** all the specifics of the context, why you need to do this, etc.* and save everybody some time wasting.